# count con inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner

Tengo 2 tablas relacionadas en `MYSQL`, **hospital y medico**. Cada médico está asignado a cada hospital y además tiene una categoría **A o B**.

Necesito una query que cuente la cantidad de categorias por hospital, les paso la estructura.

1.- tabla de hospital

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.tabla medico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

RESULTADO ESPERADO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora tengo este código, pero ojalá me puedan sugerir otro por que no me funciona.

```
select *, (
  select count(*) 
  from `medico` 
  where `hospital`.`idHospital` = `medico`.`hospital_id`
) as `medico_count` 
from `hospital`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te presento un par de propuestas... Es posible que hayan mejores soluciones u otra estructura mejor pero es lo que se me ocurren de manera rápida respetando tu estructura.

Creando las tablas e insertando datos...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hospital` (
  `id_hospital` int NOT NULL,
  `nomHospital` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_hospital`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `medico` (
  `id_medico` int NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `categoria` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `hospital_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_medico`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `hospital` (`id_hospital`, `nomHospital`) VALUES
  (1, 'Hospital_1'),
  (2, 'Hospital_2');
INSERT INTO `medico` (`id_medico`, `nombre`, `categoria`, `hospital_id`) VALUES
  (1, 'Alejandro', 'A', 1),
  (2, 'Carlos', 'B', 1),
  (3, 'Maria', 'A', 1),
  (4, 'Enrique', 'A', 2);
```

Consultando datos, propuesta uno...

```
select b.nomHospital, a.categoria, count(a.categoria) as cantidad
from medico a
inner join hospital b on a.hospital_id = b.id_hospital
group by a.categoria, a.hospital_id
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consultando datos, propuesta dos...

```
select nomHospital Hospital,
(
select count(a.hospital_id)
from medico a
where a.categoria = 'A'
and a.hospital_id = b.id_hospital
) categoria_a,
(
select count(a.hospital_id)
from medico a
where a.categoria = 'B'
and a.hospital_id = b.id_hospital
) categoria_b,
(
select count(a.hospital_id)
from medico a
where a.hospital_id = b.id_hospital
) suma
from hospital b
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probado en [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

**Edición:** Agregada la columna para obtener la sumatoria. Puedes comprobar el resultado en tu código o en el recurso que te dejé antes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Funcionó a la perfección!, me gustaría aprender más sobre este tipo de consultas, puedes recomendar algún libro o texto? Este tipo de consulta se les denominada "sub querys"?. En tu propuesta 2 si quisiera tener una columna mas donde sumar la categoria_a + categoria_b, como seria?. Disculpa las molestias.

Comment: En realidad no te sabría referenciar libros, lo poco que sé lo he aprendido sobre la marcha en esta comunidad y en la documentación oficial. En la segunda propuesta, si, son subquerys. Para obtener la suma de las dos categorías, basta con copiar el último subquery y omitir en la cláusula `where` esto: `a.categoria = 'B'`, le asignas un alias diferente y eso es todo. Edité mi respuesta para agregar esta actualización, pero te sugiero que abras una pregunta nueva si tienes más dudas al respecto para respetar las normas de la comunidad.